# JavaFX table column sorting - when cell has no value use other column's value?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a table where some cells have no known value depending on the row type.

When sorting by a column it creates a problem in that I can never achieve the correct order because the empty cells always come at the top.

I really need the sorting mechanism for each column to use it's own value if it has one, if not use a neighbouring column's value.

How can this be done? Basically, is there a way to say if cell has no value, then use a different cell's value?

Comment: Try creating a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I can't really post the existing code as there is tons with dependencies that would make no sense. It's not really a massive problem. More of a design limitation. I've now set a table sort policy that is fixed and doesn't allow column sorting which prevents this ever happening. But it would be nice to allow column sorting by multiple possible values for a cell.